# Using geom_bar to represent averages

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, geom-bar

I'm looking at daily bookings for a hotel room based on the days before arrival.

I think booking speed varies by day of week and hotel A and hotel B, so I'd like to facet by these categories.  However, when I facet (7 x 2 hotels=14 facets), it divides by the total number of dates rather than the number of dates in each category.  That is, I have 1400 unique Date-Hotels so everything is being divided by 1400 instead of approximately 100 when I facet.  I'd like my code to divide by 97,103,101 depending on how many Hotel-Dates I have in each facet so I can represent a "typical" booking pattern.

Here is my current data and code:

```
DaysBeforeArrival=rep(1:5,8)
Hotel=rep(LETTERS[1:2],20)
DayOfWeek=c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10),rep(1,10),rep(2,10))
Dates=c(rep("Jan-1",10),rep("Jan-2",10),rep("Jan-8",10),rep("Jan-9",10))
bookings=(sample(1:40))
Date_HotelID=paste(Hotel,Dates,sep="-")
mydf=data.frame(DaysBeforeArrival,Hotel,DayOfWeek,Dates,bookings,Date_HotelID)


ggplot(mydf,aes(DaysBeforeArrival,bookings/length(unique(Date_HotelID)))+
geom_bar(stat=identity)  +
facet_grid(DayofWeek~HotelID)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add a reproducible data to your question?

Comment: This should work: DaysBeforeArrival=rep(1:5,8);        
Hotel=rep(LETTERS[1:2],20);         
DayOfWeek=c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10),rep(1,10),rep(2,10));        
Dates=c(rep("Jan-1",10),rep("Jan-2",10),rep("Jan-8",10),rep("Jan-9",10));        
bookings=(sample(1:40));        
Date_HotelID=paste(Hotel,Dates,sep="-");        
df=data.frame(DaysBeforeArrival,Hotel,DayOfWeek,Dates,bookings,Date_HotelID)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted to achieve?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mydf,aes(DaysBeforeArrival,bookings/length(unique(Date_HotelID))))+
         geom_bar(stat="identity")  + facet_wrap(~Hotel~DayOfWeek)
```

[image]

Comment: I need to show a typical day (e.g. divide by the number of Date_HotelIDs in each facet window instead of divide by the total number of Date_HotelIDs)

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to simply calculate what you want to plot prior to making the graph.  In your case, you'd just need to calculate the number of unique `Date_HotelID` for each `DayOfWeek`/`Hotel` combination, and then divide `bookings` by that value for each row.

For example, I might do this with functions from *dplyr*.  Note I use `n_distinct`, which is the *dplyr* version of `length(unique(...))`.

```
library(dplyr)
mydf3 = mydf %>%
    group_by(DayOfWeek, Hotel) %>% 
    mutate(book.speed = bookings/n_distinct(Date_HotelID))
mydf3

Source: local data frame [40 x 7]
Groups: DayOfWeek, Hotel [4]

   DaysBeforeArrival  Hotel DayOfWeek  Dates bookings Date_HotelID book.speed
               (int) (fctr)     (dbl) (fctr)    (int)       (fctr)      (dbl)
1                  1      A         1  Jan-1        5      A-Jan-1        2.5
2                  2      B         1  Jan-1       34      B-Jan-1       17.0
3                  3      A         1  Jan-1       20      A-Jan-1       10.0
4                  4      B         1  Jan-1       11      B-Jan-1        5.5
5                  5      A         1  Jan-1       13      A-Jan-1        6.5
6                  1      B         1  Jan-1       38      B-Jan-1       19.0
7                  2      A         1  Jan-1        7      A-Jan-1        3.5
8                  3      B         1  Jan-1       15      B-Jan-1        7.5
9                  4      A         1  Jan-1       22      A-Jan-1       11.0
10                 5      B         1  Jan-1       14      B-Jan-1        7.0
..               ...    ...       ...    ...      ...          ...        ...
```

The just make your graph with the calculated data.

```
ggplot(mydf3, aes(DaysBeforeArrival, book.speed)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity")  +
    facet_grid(DayOfWeek ~ Hotel)
```

[image]